# Meteor Connection error (connect ETIMEDOUT)

Tags: meteor

I am trying to deploy or delete or even check logs of my app deployed at

> homlia-cc.meteor.com

but I get this error

```
Error deploying application: Connection error (connect ETIMEDOUT).
```

Comment: Having the same issue.

Comment: I've tried this just now from another IP address and it worked. I suspect a firewall is blocking me at home, or meteor is blocking my home IP?

Comment: But how to test that? I have removed the firewall but it is still not working. I suspect it has, maybe, something to do with the latest meteor version.

Comment: See also the issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5578)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue as well. Worked sometimes after just trying again.

Activating a VPN solved my issue more often. Not sure if this is on our or Meteors side but trying a VPN might help you.